# Where can I check my message content while using Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm new to the Azure Messaging Service while we choose to start with Service Bus Queue, everything works fine at beginning and it worked pretty well! However, later on at sometimes when we tried to debug our service bus azure functions, after we sent the message to the queue, our subscriber function does not trigger somehow, it's like something blocked/hold there while we have no idea what was going on. Meanwhile, we can see there are numbers of **Active Messages** and **Dead-letter Message** displayed in our Azure portal Service Bus Queue Explorer, however, **we couldn't figure out a way to see what these active/dead-letter messages' content looks like so we have no idea what we sent into the queue and what kind messages block the queue subscriber**. Is there anyway we can store the message content somewhere in **either blob storage or our own database**, it could be much better if somehow Azure could tell us when this message sent into the queue, message's status, what happened that it becomes the dead-letter queue, etc.

FYI, other times when we found our subscriber stopped trigger, we shut down the current one and restart a new instance, then all messages came in immediately...But question is, **why would our previous subscriber failed to trigger while there is active message entered the queue?**

Comment: Can you verify your function app was up and running or not throwing any exception while processing the message.

Comment: I am sure my function app was up and running as I'm in debugging mode, I actually had 2 functions in my project, the first one is Httptrigger where I used for starting unit testing, and it will send message to my service bus queue while my second function is the service bus queue trigger/listener, when I trigger my function 1 and see my message goes in the queue as "active message", but my function 2 didn't trigger at that moment for a while. Like I said until I stop and then restart my debugging, I saw this time my function 2 wake up and start processing.